# Proper Way to Plot with GNUPlot? (C++ 14, VS 22)

Tags: c++, gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I'm attempting to graph some data with the `GNUPlot` library in C++.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with C++ 14. I also installed the `boost` libraries and am using the `gnuplot-iostream.h` file from [dsthalke's GitHib repository](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream).

As far as I understand, `GNUPlot` is different than `MatPlotLib` in the sense that it is a lower-level method of plotting data. As far as I understand, it consists of sending a series of commands via the `<<` operator to a variable of type of `Gnuplot`.

I've been attempting to plot a few basic examples, from the [GNUPlot documentation website](http://stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) and other examples.

Attempting to run Example 1 and 2 from the documentation website results in nothing happening, and the message `pclose return error: No error`.

Attempting to run any of the examples from [this website](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/%7Evalliere/PHYS305/basic_graphics/basic_graphics.html) also results in the same output.

That is, the following example code from the above website:

```
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"

int main()
{
    Gnuplot plot;
    
    plot << "set dgrid3d 200,200,1";
    plot << "set pm3d";
    plot << "set palette";
    plot << "set palette color";
    plot << "set pm3d map";
    plot << "splot \"sin_cos_data\"";

    return 0;
}
```

Also results in nothing.

How does one graph data with `GNUPlot` in C++?
Is there a different set of examples that I have not yet come accross, that would be better for explaining how to do it?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to get any plot out your C++ code that uses Gnuplot library? Or are you asking how to learn Gnuplot commands? The latter is a totally different story and probably off topic here, as that would be a very broad question.

Comment: Linked gnuplot-iostream documentation states you need at least `\n` at the end of each command: `Don't forget to put "\n" at the end of each line!`: `gp << "set xrange [-2:2]\nset yrange [-2:2]\n";`

Comment: Also it seems there [may be troubles](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream/wiki/Portability#windows) on Windows: _When the Gnuplot object goes out of scope, the pipe is closed and gnuplot exits. This can be cured by instead using pgnuplot, but that is deprecated and seems to garble data. Perhaps better is to prompt the user to press a key before exiting your program (and before letting the Gnuplot object go out of scope)._

Comment: I would first like to get any plot working with GNUPlot, whether it be an example plot or some sample data. I also tried puttin the newline character after every command, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's embarrassing...
Turns out I didn't actually [install the GNUPlot library](http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html) separately.

Talk about rushing...